# Evaluate Integral with $e^{ut}\ \Gamma (u)^{2}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, laplace-transform, contour-integration, cauchy-principal-value

I am trying to integrate this integral:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi j}\int_{c-j\infty}^{c+j\infty}x^{-s}\sigma ^{ms-m}\left [ \frac{\Gamma \left ( \frac{s}{\beta} \right )}{\Gamma \left ( \frac{1}{\beta} \right )} \right ]^{m}ds$$
where $\sigma>0$, $\beta>0$, $m>0$ and both $\beta$ and $m$ are positive integers

For $m=2$, I need help continuing after simplifying to this form below:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi \sigma^{2} j \Gamma \left ( \frac{1}{\beta} \right )^{2}}\int_{c-j\infty}^{c+j\infty}\left ( \frac{\sigma^{2}}{x} \right )^{s}\Gamma \left ( \frac{s}{\beta} \right )^{2}ds$$

Which I managed to simplify to following form:
$$f(x)=\frac{\beta}{2\pi \sigma^{2} j \Gamma \left ( \frac{1}{\beta} \right )^{2}}\int_{c-j\infty}^{c+j\infty}e^{ut}\ \Gamma \left (u \right )^{2}du$$

How to further simplify the following integral using Cauchy's residue theorem for multiple poles due to $\Gamma \left (u \right )^{2}$?
$$\int_{c-j\infty}^{c+j\infty}e^{ut}\ \Gamma \left (u \right )^{2}du$$

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT**

The previous versions of this answer contained an error.  I have now corrected the error and have verified its veracity.

---

Let's look at your last integral, which may be evaluated using a simple Bromwich contour and the residue theorem.  Really, for $t \gt 0$,

$$\int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} du \, e^{u t} \Gamma(u)^2 = i 2 \pi \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \operatorname*{Res}_{z=-n} e^{z t} \Gamma(z)^2 $$

Now we know that $\Gamma$ has the form, near $z=-n$ of

$$\Gamma(z) = \frac{a_{-1}}{z+n} + a_0 + O(z+n)$$

where $a_{-1} = (-1)^n/n!$ and

$$a_0 = \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \left ( \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k} - \gamma \right ) = \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \left ( H_n - \gamma \right ) $$

This result may be derived from the relation

$$\Gamma(-n+\epsilon) \Gamma(n+1-\epsilon) = (-1)^{n} \frac{\pi}{\sin{\pi \epsilon}} $$

which means that

$$\Gamma(-n+\epsilon) = \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \frac1{\epsilon} + \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \left ( H_n - \gamma \right ) + O(\epsilon)$$

Thus,

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=-n} \left [ e^{t z} \Gamma(z)^2 \right ] = a_{-1}^2 t + 2 a_{-1} a_0 = 2 \frac{H_n-\gamma+t/2}{n!^2}$$

Now, the integral we seek is

$$\int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} du \, e^{u t} \Gamma(u)^2 = i 2 \pi \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2 (H_n-\gamma) + t}{n!^2} e^{-n t} $$

Now,

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!^2} = I_0 \left ( 2 \sqrt{z} \right ) $$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} H_n \frac{z^n}{n!^2} =K_0 \left ( 2 \sqrt{z} \right ) + \left ( \frac12 \log{z} + \gamma \right ) I_0 \left ( 2 \sqrt{z} \right )$$

where $I_0$ and $K_0$ are modified Bessel functions of the first and second kind, respectively, of zeroth order.  These sums result from the respective expansions of $I_0$ and $K_0$ for small argument.

Subbing $z=e^{-t}$, we finally arrive at the value of the integral:

> $$\int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} du \, e^{u t} \Gamma(u)^2 = i 2 \pi
>  \cdot 2 K_0 \left ( 2 e^{-t/2} \right )  $$

This is a *two-sided transform*, or a Mellin transform.  (This was the original formulation of the problem.)  The below derivation illustrates why.

**ADDENDUM**

I assumed that the first equation above is valid, but did not demonstrate how this is so.  To see this, we must show that

$$R \int_{\pi/2}^{3 \pi/2} d\theta \, \left | \Gamma \left (R e^{i \theta} \right )^2 \right | e^{R t \cos{\theta}} $$

vanishes as $R \to \infty$.

Use Stirling's approximation:

$$\left |\Gamma \left (R e^{i \theta} \right )^2  \right | \sim \frac{2 \pi}{R} e^{2 R \log{R} \cos{\theta} -2 R \theta \sin{\theta}} e^{-2 R \cos{\theta}}  $$

The term $R \log{R} \cos{\theta}$ dominates the other terms in the exponential, so that the behavior of this term is

$$\left |\Gamma \left (R e^{i \theta} \right )^2 \right | \sim \frac{2 \pi}{R} e^{2 R \log{R} \cos{\theta}} $$

Thus,

$$R \int_{\pi/2}^{3 \pi/2} d\theta \, \left | \Gamma \left (R e^{i \theta} \right ) \right |^2 e^{R t \cos{\theta}} \sim \frac{\pi^2}{R \log{R}} \quad (R \to \infty)$$

which indeed vanishes in the desired limit.

Note that the above criterion is *independent* of $t$.  Thus, the transform is two-sided and not causal as was previously stated.

Comment: thanks a lot! I will need some time to go through. May i know what is $H_n$ please?

Comment: $$H_n =\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k}$$ is the $n$th harmonic number.

Comment: @arvindrajan92: just out of curiosity, in what context did you find this integral?

Comment: $\sigma ^{ms-m}\left [ \frac{\Gamma \left ( \frac{s}{\beta} \right )}{\Gamma \left ( \frac{1}{\beta} \right )} \right ]^{m}$ is the Mellin transform of product of $m$ independent exponential type distributions. I want to find the PDF by using inverse Mellin. Thats how I came about this integral

Comment: @arvindrajan92: I meant, how did you come across the integral?  (i.e., from a book, in the line of work or research, and if so, into what?)

Comment: oh, sorry. it is part of my research. into analytical evaluation of distributions. and one of them is the exponential type distribution

Comment: musnt it be $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{H_n-\gamma}{n!^2} e^{-n t}$ instead of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n-\gamma}{n!^2} e^{-n t}$?

Comment: @arvindrajan92: yes.  Thanks for catching the typo.

Comment: why did u find the $\operatorname*{Res}_{z=-n} \Gamma(z)^2$ and not $\operatorname*{Res}_{z=-n} e^{z t} \Gamma(z)^2$? isnt $f(z)=e^{z t} \Gamma(z)^2$?

Comment: @arvindrajan92: I apologize - I was wrong in the above comment.  The exponential does matter because there is a double pole as well, so we do have to expand the exponential to capture an additional contribution to the residue.  Anyway, the result is above and is much cleaner.  It also jibes with Whittaker & Watson, Sec. 13-21, Equation 8 (which references a result from Heaviside's *Electromagnetic Theory* from 1912).

Comment: thank you very much for the correction. I was quite puzzled when you said it doesnt matter. thanks again :)

Comment: @arvindrajan92: also note that this is a two-sided transform, although the original form of the integral should have made this clear.  This means that the above transform is valid even when $x \gt \sigma^2$.  This messed me up for a long time when I was checking the result.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll take my time to go through now. Apologies for the delayed response