# Series Expansion of the Incomplete Gamma Function

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function

The incomplete gamma function (upper) is defined as $\Gamma(a,x)=\int_x^{\infty}t^{a-1}e^{-t}dt$. Is there a series expansion for small non-integer $a << 1$ and small $x$?

Comment: You want an expansion around $x=0$  assuming $a \in (0,1)$ ? Did you notice that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \Gamma(a,x) = -x^{a-1} e^{-x}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2143157/what-is-this-series-relating-to-the-residues-of-the-gamma-function), we know that

$$\Gamma(a,x)=\Gamma(a)-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{a+n}}{n!(a+n)}$$

Which follows from the Taylor expansion of $e^x$.